# QT5 Slot not called in subclass

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have a superclass `BackgroundWorkerWithWaitDialog` that manages a `WaitDialog` that implements a progress bar box with an "abort" button. It is used as a QObject in a QThread.

My intention is to derive any background task from BackgroundWorker and implement only the `execute()` command, polling for an `aborted` flag to stop it.

BackgroundWorkerWithWaitDialog is derived from `BackgroundWorker` that is a QObject, all classes are Q_OBJECT and the worker classes are able to update the gui using signals and slots. This communication (Worker to Gui Object) is working correctly.

The problem is that though WaitDialog responds to the pushbutton click, the `aborted()` signal is emitted from the WaitDialog but isn't received by the BackGroundWorker. (Gui -> Worker)

```
class WaitDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit WaitDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~WaitDialog();

public slots:
    void setText(QString text);
    void setProgress(bool shown, int max);
    void enableAbort(bool enable);
    void setProgression (int level);

signals:
    void aborted();

private slots:
    void on_cmdAbort_clicked();

private:
    Ui::WaitDialog *ui;

};


void WaitDialog::on_cmdAbort_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "ABORT";
    emit aborted();
}
```

...

```
/// BackgroundWorker is QObject-derived.
class BackgroundWorkerWithWaitDialog : public BackgroundWorker
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit BackgroundWorkerWithWaitDialog(MainWindow *main, WaitDialog *dialog);
...
public slots:
    virtual void abortIssued();
```

....

```
BackgroundWorkerWithWaitDialog::BackgroundWorkerWithWaitDialog(MainWindow *main, WaitDialog *dialog)
: BackgroundWorker(main),
  mWaitDialog(dialog),
  mAborted(false)
{
    connect (this, SIGNAL(progress(int)), mWaitDialog, SLOT(setProgression(int)));
    connect (this, SIGNAL(messageChanged(QString)), mWaitDialog, SLOT(setText(QString)));
    connect (this, SIGNAL(progressBarVisibilityChanged(bool,int)), mWaitDialog, SLOT(setProgress(bool,int)));
    connect (this, SIGNAL(abortButtonVisibilityChanged(bool)), mWaitDialog, SLOT(enableAbort(bool)));
    connect (mWaitDialog, SIGNAL(aborted()), this, SLOT(abortIssued()));
}

void BackgroundWorkerWithWaitDialog::abortIssued()
{
    // THIS IS NEVER EXECUTED
    mAborted = true;
}
```

Is there something I am missing? I temporarily fixed this with a listener pattern, but frankly I don't like this hybrid fix.

Why isn't the abortIssued slot not called ?

Thanks in advance.

---

So to summarize:

- BackgroundWorkerWithWaitDialog (BWWWD) derives from BackgroundWorker that inherits from QObject
- BackgroundWorkerWithWaitDialog receive in the constructor a WaitDialog (WD) that is derived from QDialog
- BWWWD in the constructor connect()s the waitDialog aborted() signal with the abortIssued() slot
- WD emits the signal but abortIssued isn't called
- BWWWD is executed in a separate QThread

---

It would worth saying that BWWWD class is derived by other SpecificWorker classes that implements specific functions that make use of the aborted() function to interrupt the processing.

Answer (score 0):

Your question states:

> i have a superclass BackgroundWorker that manages a WaitDialog that implements a progress bar box with an "abort" button.

In the `BackgroundWorkerWithWaitDialog` constructor you do not pass `dialog` to `BackgroundWorker`'s constructor, nor do you use a `BackgroundWorker` member variable when you are setting up your connections.

Either your questions opening statement is wrong, or you are connecting to a dialog that is never used.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: You're right, I am correcting the text. I wanted to simplify the context, but indeed I forgot to change some name in the code. The BackgroundWorker knows nothing about dialog, it's a generic QObject used in a QThread; and the waitdialog is connected correctly in the BackgroundWorkerWithGui.

Comment: @HappyCactus So to confirm, you could just totally leave `BackgroundWorker` out of your question and it wouldn't change anything? If that is the case get your edit on.

Comment: Well, not 100% sure, but I am confident that the BW class can be left out. WaitDialog just have relation with BWWWD, and signals/slots between the two are concerned. Thanks.

Comment: @HappyCactus So I would start by making "BWWWD" a class that doesn't inherit from "BW" and see what happens. If that doesn't solve the problem you need to adapt your question, cause then it's a `connect` question having nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: @NKN "Either your questions opening statement is wrong, or you are connecting to a dialog that is never used." I still believe this to be the answer to why the OP's connection isn't working. This *is* an answer.